# Classic ASP: General access denied error

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory

I have a system, written in Classic ASP, which reads data from a form and updates AD. I am, however, getting the following error when I try and update my own information:

Active Directory error '80070005'

General access denied error

/activedirectory/index.asp, line 99

Line 99 is

```
objUser.SetInfo
```

and the entire code block is as follows:

```
 <%
 uname = request.querystring("account_name")
 ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal"
 Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
 objCon.Properties("User ID") = "NETWORK\example"
 objCon.Properties("Password") = "PaSsWoRd"
 objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
 objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
 objCom.CommandText ="select distinguishedName FROM '"+ ADUser +"' where sAMAccountname='"& uname &"'"
 Set objRS = objCom.Execute
  distinguishedName = objRS.Fields("distinguishedName")
 'Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2 
 Set objUser = GetObject _
 ("LDAP://" & distinguishedName) 
 objUser.Put "givenName", firstname
 objUser.Put "mail", email
 objUser.Put "sn", lastname
 objUser.Put "mobile", mobile
 objUser.Put "description", description
 objUser.Put "telephoneNumber", telephonenumber
 objUser.Put "department", department
 objUser.Put "title", title
 objUser.Put "company", company
 objUser.SetInfo
 Response.Write("User data for "& uname &" has been modified. Click <a href='/'>here</a> to go home")
%>
```

I have gone through the troubleshooting steps that I can think of, ensuring the password I am using is correct, making sure the account has delegated write permissions, etc. Some pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: Which version of IIS? What authentication/impersonation method(s) are you using?

Comment: The version of IIS is IIS7 on a Windows 2008 box. The authentication on the page that updates AD is anonymous access but the page that shows the form and takes input is Windows authentication.